# SQLite command in program.cs file

Tags: c#, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I wrote a program with C# and .NET2 when I used SQL command like: "SQLiteConnection" in the program.cs file I encountered to the following error:

> [program name] has encountered a problem and needs to close.  We are
>   sorry for the inconvenience.

This error only appears in other computers and in my computer that I have written the program with, the program runs without any difficulties.

Comment: What target CPU did you compile your program for? It is possible that the SQLite libraries are only available for x86 and you're compiling for `AnyCPU`, which results in a crash when trying to run the program on a 64 bit system.

Comment: Probably an exception you didn't catch. Add some logs to diagnose the issue.

Comment: Are you sure that all necessary libraries for SQLite are being deployed to the other computers along with your application?

Comment: You might try installing sqllite via the MSI on one of the computers with the issue. My guess is you aren't deploying all of the required libraries

Comment: Do you deploy [tag:system.data.sqlite] assembly? You can also merge it in your executable.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper is right. SQLite has x86 and x64 version. I believe that this is why you are getting this error. I had the same problem in the past. I solved creating two versions of the app. One referencing x64 and other referencing x86.